How to use FontAwesome in NavigationViewItem of WPF UI
I want to use FontAwesome instead Fluent Icons System on NavigationViewItem. I'm using the UI framework https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui
So i loaded the FontAwesome and use that code, it show an empty square like font are not loaded
            new NavigationViewItem()
            {
                Content = "Home",
                Icon = new FontIcon { Glyph = "\uf015", FontFamily = new FontFamily("FontAwesome") },
                TargetPageType = typeof(Views.Pages.DashboardPage)
            },

instead original code

            new NavigationViewItem()
            {
                Content = "Home",
                Icon = new SymbolIcon { Symbol = SymbolRegular.Empty },
                TargetPageType = typeof(Views.Pages.DashboardPage)
            },

reference: https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui/blob/303f0aefcd59a142bc681415dc4360a34a15f33d/src/Wpf.Ui/Controls/NavigationView/NavigationViewItem.cs#L236
If i use the code below it works fine
<TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}"
       FontSize="48"
       Text="&#xf015;"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

Any idea if we can do that?
Thanks for answsers
